# Как устроен реестр p2p участников блокчейна, майнеров, транзакций?

Tags: bitcoin, p2p, blockchain, криптовалюта

Ребята привет!
Пытаюсь разложить у себя в понимании по полочкам крипту и блокчейн, возникли пару вопросов.
Разбираю на примере bitcoin. Я хочу понять суть, а не как пользовать софтом из коробки, застрял немного, подскажите пожалуйста:

Вопрос про P2P в крипте: чтобы соединить хотябы 2 человека по сети нужен сервер и клиент, т.е. клиент должен знать ip и порт сервера.
Как майнеры и участники сделок находят друг друга? Вот хочу я отправить btc например, кто принимает мой запрос? Куда отправляется запрос после нажатия "отправить" в btccore? Должен быть единый сервер какой то чтоли? Наподобии ТОРРЕНТ-ТРЕКЕРА. Т.е. справочники: очереди транзакций на обработку и майнеров. Какой у него адрес? А как он защищен неужели его ниразу не ddosили?
А если майнер нашел тот волшебный ключ с нулями для определенного блока транзакций, как он находит участников сети, чтобы им поделиться?

И воторой вопрос: что если одна и таже транзакция попадет в два блока или более блоков, мой блок чейн это проигнорит? Как достигается синхронность миллиардов блоков если нет единой очереди транзакций? Как майнеры набирают себе блок транзакций? А что если манер наберет себе сам блок транзакций и будет решать его год - он получит вознаграждение? И кто начисляет это вознаграждение за найденный хеш?

Спасибо! Очень жду ответы)))